# Error: sudo apt update in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

```
(base) rahul0324@rahul0324-Predator-G3-572:~$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
 Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (10.8.0.100), connection timed out
Err:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
 Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
 Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
 Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (10.8.0.100), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

### sources.list

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates universe 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates multiverse 
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
```

**Note - I have already checked by changing "downloads from"  in software & Updates.**

Comment: Seems that in.archive.ubuntu.com have been unreachable, could you ping or open it on your browser?

Comment: @PasiSuominen I can't even open in my browser saying "This site can’t be reached".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an inaccurate or inactive mirror you're trying to use in your sources list.  It may help to look at the webpage below, and find the country you are in and the mirror URL you should use.  That would be where I would start, since everything else seems to be downloading properly, according to your output of apt update.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Comment: After selecting the country which mirror URL should I select?

Comment: And after selecting the mirror URL how to proceed further?

Comment: When you click on the mirror link, you'll see "mirror location information"  just change your sources list to mirror (pun not intended) the mirror location.  So, change http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ to http://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ for example.  Leave the rest of the line the same (bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse) - using your first entry in sources list that points to in.archive.ubuntu.com   Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix my issue using the Software Sources utility found in Ubuntu.

Under "Official Repositories" select "Restore the default settings". It appeared to update my sources list and I was able to update again.

[image: Software Sources utility in Linux Mint]

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing reset the sources of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and it worked.

To do so follow these steps:

1. Check the release of your ubuntu version by `lsb_release -r`
2. From this `http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/` generate a new `sources.list`
3. Select your country and release
4. Check the first 12 boxes
5. Generate and copy your new list
6. Backup the old file to sources.list.backup
   `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup`
7. Now open your editor and save the new list  `sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list`
8. Try again `sudo apt update` :)

Comment: When I checked, the tool at repogen.simplylinux.ch only had Linux versions up to and including Bionic 18.04. It also seemed pretty minimal as well.